# SQL 0 if negative value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So I want to turn negative value's into a 0. I found 2 solutions that do exactly the same:

```
SUM(IF(ordered_item.amount < 0, 0, ordered_item.amount)) as purchases
```

And

```
SUM(CASE WHEN ordered_item.amount < 0 THEN 0 ELSE ordered_item.amount END) as purchases
```

They give me both the same result, but which would give me the best *performance*? And is there maybe a *simpler* solution to turn negatives into `0`.

Comment: Why not just `MAX(ordered_item.amount, 0)`?

Comment: You could use `EXPLAIN {{QUERY}}` to check which query is more complex

Comment: In most RDBMSs it's likely that the query planner will generate the same execution plan for something like this.  Use `EXPLAIN` on each query like @Germanaz0 suggests.

Comment: @PavelGatnar The rest of the query is irrelevant. I just wanted to know a better and maybe faster solution for the `SUM(IF... or CASE`

Comment: @BramDriesen do you need to go through the rows with negative amount?

Comment: @PavelGatnar yes I need to be able to do a count to see how many `orders` have been placed. So excluding the negatives from the results would not work. That's why I need to just convert the negatives to 0.

Comment: OP, based on @Germanaz0 explanation, I ran an EXPLAIN on your two suggestions as well as one of the suggested answers on a Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90f21/3 All three are the same, so pick the one you find most readable and likely most maintainable in the future.

Comment: @McAdam331 Wow awesome! The `GREATEST` solution seems to execute faster though. At 0ms while the others are at 1ms

Comment: Bram, good! Also, @mikeTheLiar, you were very much on the right track but I feel I should point out that `MAX()` does not take more than one parameter. If you want to do something like that, you need `GREATEST()`, as has already been mentioned.

Comment: @McAdam331 yeah, I wasn't sure about the flavor of SQL we were talking about, I was assuming TSQL but looks like it's mySQL. Conceptually the same.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

An alternate approach you could use is the [GREATEST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function.

```
SUM(GREATEST(ordered_item.amount, 0)) as purchases
```

Comment: I like this solution the most. Anytime you can accomplish the same task in fewer lines of SQL is a good thing, IMO. Even better is that it has the same performance as OP's suggestions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90f21/3

Comment: Would be nice if there was a T-SQL equivalent

Comment: Is the SUM necessary?

Comment: @DropDropped Yes indeed. The OP wanted a way to sum all positive values in the `amount` column while ignoring the negatives.

Comment: Perfect solution! I'm using it to decrement a filed down to zero without going negative

Answer (score 5):

You can define the field as "unsigned" so no conversion would be required

```
CREATE TABLE ordered_item ( 
order_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
amount INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`order_id `) 
);
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: I'm not allowed to alter the table, but great answer! I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks

Comment: This solution is technically not right since OP wanted a solution that turn negative values into 0. This solution would return an INT UNSIGNED error if a negative value was to be inserted into the table :)

Answer (score 5):

Haven't seen this answer, so how about implementing math logic:

> (abs(x)+x)/2

Trying with 5 and -5 gives 5 and 0 respectively.
Not sure if it is calculation intensive, but it's easy to write:

```
Select (ABS(ordered_item.amount) + ordered_item.amount ) / 2 as purchases
from ordered_item
```

Let me know the speed if you get to try it with your dataset, I am getting similar speeds.

Comment: I was looking for an elegant solution for making value A = -1 if value B is negative and value A = 1 if value B is positive and this nudged me in the right directioin: x/abs(x)

Comment: Great answer. Math is always the better answer.